# Override Framework class with custom class

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to override UIColor to return a different colour as label but I'm struggling to wrap my head around how this is supposed to be done.

The idea is that whenever anything is trying to get UIColor.label (storyboards etc.) instead of getting the default system colour it gets my custom colour instead.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class UIColor: UIKit.UIColor {

    override class var label: UIKit.UIColor {
        return red
    }
}
```

However storyboards is still getting UIKit.UIColor instead of my custom UIColor.
What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think you're looking for swizzling. This article has an example, even dealing with colors: https://abhimuralidharan.medium.com/method-swizzling-in-ios-swift-1f38edaf984f

Comment: There is no right way. The runtime is never going to call in to your “UIColor” to get a color, any more than it would call in to your “HeyHo” to get a color. You would need to meddle with the internals of the real UIColor (swizzling)! Is that really where you want to take this?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! And thanks for the link @jnpdx. Yes it looks like "swizzling" is what I'm looking to do.